# IBMs varnish operator is deployed but status is pending while using helm

Tags: kubernetes, varnish

Trying to use Varnish operator to setup Varnish cache in Kubernetes, added Helm chart and deployed repo but pod status is still pending.

Here is the link I followed
https://ibm.github.io/varnish-operator/quick-start.html

Kubernetes version - 1.21.5

[image]

Comment: can't you look at the events in the namespace or describe, to see what is going on?

Comment: Please provide more information about your current setup - which Kubernetes version are you using, which solution did you use to setup a cluster (kubeadm or some cloud provider solution etc.).

Comment: I've reproduced your steps and it works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @Eugene i had look for events in namespace

| LAST SEEN | TYPE | REASON | OBJECT | MESSAGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2m29s | Warning | FailedScheduling | pod/varnish-operator-5596dbb797-s6ncq | 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Insufficient cpu. |
| 4m34s | Normal | NotTriggerScaleUp | pod/varnish-operator-5596dbb797-s6ncq | pod didn't trigger scale-up: |

I have increased CPU, issue solved thanks every one.

Comment: good thing it worked for you!